# ARKit 3 : Enable tracking only to the ARAnchor at the center of the screen

Tags: ios, arkit, swift5, xcode11, arimageanchor

I want to display a SCNNode above the tracked image which is the closest to the center of the camera.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

I tried to hide all others nodes/anchors and only keep current one in this renderer function but nothing worked.

My goal is to display a 3D object when an image is tracked and when another image is found, the tracking is enabled on the image closest to the center of the camera.

**Is there a way to specify which ARAnchor on the camera to track or to hide other ARAnchors?**

Comment: (My configuration is set to ARImageTrackingConfiguration)

Comment: I never implemented an app that uses `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`, but have you tried setting [maximumNumberOfTrackedImages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration/2968174-maximumnumberoftrackedimages) to 1?

Comment: Yes I did that but the problem still remain, the tracking remains until the picture isn't visible to the camera.

I was thinking to set **maximumNumberOfTrackedImages**                       
A - to **2** and hide the farest ArAnchor 
B -  to **1** and constantly tells to the render to switch his focus to the nearest ArAnchor.

The solution A didn't work or I didn't do it right and  for the solution B, I don't have any idea how to do that.

Comment: The idea of the solution B is like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454599/arkit-select-what-arimageanchor-to-track